# Pandas: add crosstab totals

Tags: python, pandas

How can I add to my crosstab an additional row and an additional column for the totals?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randint(0,2,100), "B" : np.random.randint(0,2,100)})
ct = pd.crosstab(new.A, new.B)
ct
```

[image]

I thought I would add the new column (obtained by summing over the rows) by

```
ct["Total"] = ct.0 + ct.1
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because 'attribute-like' column access does not work with integer column names. Using the standard indexing:

```
In [122]: ct["Total"] = ct[0] + ct[1]

In [123]: ct
Out[123]:
B   0   1  Total
A
0  26  24     50
1  30  20     50
```

See the warnings at the end of this section in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access

When you want to work with the rows, you can use `.loc`:

```
In [126]: ct.loc["Total"] = ct.loc[0] + ct.loc[1]
```

In this case `ct.loc["Total"]` is equivalent to `ct.loc["Total", :]`

Comment: Oh perfect thanks. What about the additional row? Is there a similar way?

Answer (score 45):

In fact `pandas.crosstab` already provides an option `margins`, which does exactly what you want.

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randint(0,2,100), "B" : np.random.randint(0,2,100)})
> pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B, margins=True)
B     0   1  All
A               
0    26  21   47
1    25  28   53
All  51  49  100
```

Basically, by setting `margins=True`, the resulting frequency table will add an "All" column and an "All" row that compute the subtotals.

Comment: If you don't like the name "All", you can rename it using `margins_name="Total"` or any other string you like: `pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B, margins=True, margins_name="Total")`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the margins=True for this along with crosstab. That should do the job!