# How to search by using different columns

Tags: pandas

Gender and city are two different columns. I want to search in such a way that how many males and Females from Gender column in particular city in Pandas

Comment: df[df['city'] == 'NY']['Gender'].value_counts().. i guess would work

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.city, df.gender)` ?

Comment: Thanks Chris. I need to have total no of Males and Females for all cities please.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032910)

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'LA'],
    'gender': ['m', 'f', 'f', 'm']})

z = df.groupby(['city', 'gender']).size()
z
```

Output:

```
city  gender
LA    m         1
NY    f         2
      m         1
```

To check distribution in one city, e.g. NY:

```
z = df.groupby(['city', 'gender']).size()
z['NY']
```

Output:

```
gender
f    2
m    1
```

Comment: for df["Gender"].value_counts(dropna=False)
Male      389648
Female     84544
NaN        64673        
Name: Gender, dtype: int64                                                                                                     In same if I want to find total males and Females for particular city.

Comment: If you have "City" column, run `df.groupby(['City', 'Gender']).size()`

Comment: for df["Gender"].value_counts(dropna=False)
Male      389648
Female     84544
NaN        64673                                                                                                                 if I want to find total males and Fmale for particular city.                                                                                                                                                              ex:  NY                London                                     
    Male:23        Male:74                         
   Fmale:23     Fmale:47

Comment: Updated my answer with an example